# Can I accomplish this query in a single LINQ query?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a complex situation I'm trying to solve, but my skills with both SQL and LINQ are moderate at best and I can't see how to accomplish this. I can do it with multiple queries, but I'd love to know if I can do it with one.

I have a `Pricing` table in SQL. The three fields I care about are `SearchCodeGUID`, `LocationGUID`, and `ClientGUID`. Location and Client are both nullable.

When performing my query, I have a SearchGUID, a StateGUID, a CountyGUID, and a ClientGUID. Below are the queries I want to execute. For all of these, I want where `SearchGUID = SearchGUID`. The order of operations works like such:

First I want to check if a Client has a price for the County - Where `ClientGUID = ClientGUID` and `LocationGUID = CountyGUID`

If that doesn't exist, I want to see if there's a record for just that county - where `LocationGUID = CountyGUID`

If that doesn't exist I want to see if there's a record for that state - where `LocationGUID = StateGUID`

Lastly, if that doesn't exist, I simply want the record where `LocationGUID` and `ClientGUID` are null and the `SearchGUID` matches.

Comment: What's your current code?

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance I don't have any current code, I can't even begin to think of how I'd manage this in any way that wasn't very messy. Currently I do this with separate queries

Comment: @cost - post your current separate queries - someone might see a way to combine them looking at them with a fresh set of eyes.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is with OrderBy:

```
IQueryable<Pricing> table = ...
var matches = table.Where(p => p.SearchGUID = searchGUID);
var result = matches.Select(p => new
{
    pricing = p 
    // 0 score if client & county match 
    score = p.ClientGUID == clientGUID && p.LocationGUID == countyGUID 
        ? 0
        // 1 score if just county match
        : p.LocationGUID == countyGUID
            ? 1
            // 2 score if just state match
            : p.LocationGUID == stateGUID
                ? 2
                // 3 score if client & location are null
                : p.ClientGUID == null && p.LocationGUID == null
                    ? 3
                    // 4 score if it missed all conditions
                    : 4
 })
 .Where(t => t.score < 4) // eliminate mismatches
 .OrderBy(t => t.score) // put low scores first
 .Select(t => t.pricing) // if we want to read just the pricing entity, select it
 .FirstOrDefault(); // take the first match, or null if no match was found
```

Comment: Oh that's an interesting idea, let me try this out. I also wonder what the speed difference between this and the separate queries is

Comment: @cost: that's something you'll have to profile. In many cases round trip time is longer than query time, so running just one query is better. On the other hand, with the multi-query system you can run just one simple query if the first condition matches, which may be better if that happens a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I like Chase's answer but I figured I'd post a more traditional one.  Given a lazy list over a large amount of data this is probably faster... but I make no claims since I really have no clue about your actual data model.

```
  var idMatch = Pricing.Select(p => p.SearchCodeGUID == SearchGUID);

  var countyMatch = idMatch.Select(p => p.LocationGUID == CountyGUID);

  if (countryMatch.Any()) // match one of two first cases
  {
     var clientToo = countyMatch.Select(p => p.ClientGUID == ClientGUID)
                       .FristOrDefault();

     if (clientToo != null)
       return(clientToo);
     else
       return(countyMatch.First());
  }

  var stateMatch = idMatch.Select(p => p.LocationGUID == stateGUID)
                     .FirstOrDefault();

  if (stateMatch != null) 
    return(stateMatch);

  return(idMatch.Select(p => (LocationGUID == null) && (ClientGUID == null))
           .FirstOrDefault());
```

Comment: Another interesting solution. I think I'm going to play with both yours and Chase's answers and see how each works out